# How do I create a delegate for a property getter from an open generic type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have a PropertyInfo for a property on an open generic type, obtained in the following way:

```
public interface ITest<T>
{
    T Item { get; }
}

var propertyInfo = typeof(ITest<>).GetProperty("Item");
```

I'd like to be able to create a concrete, callable delegate, filling in the class type parameter (e.g. `Func<ITest<int>, int>`) from `propertyInfo`.

The obvious thing to try is `propertyInfo.GetMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(int)).CreateDelegate(...)`, but this fails because `GetMethod` isn't generic - it's a property on a generic class.

I know you can get a delegate for this property by applying the type parameter to the type earlier on (e.g. `typeof(ITest<int>).GetProperty("Item").GetMethod.CreateDelegate(...)`), but I was hoping to only have to look for the property in `ITest` once, given that it'll be the same search repeated for each type parameter otherwise.

Is there a way to create this delegate, or can it only come about by using `typeof(ITest<int>)` to start with?

**Short Version**

Can `TestMethod` below be made to pass by some implementation of `CreateGetter` (assuming `T::Equals` is implemented sensibly)?

```
public void TestMethod<T>(ITest<T> x)
{
    var propertyInfo = typeof(ITest<>).GetProperty("Item");
    var getter = CreateGetter<int>(propertyInfo);

    Assert(getter(x).Equals(x.Item));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to use a `PropertyInfo`, this Method will work:

```
public static Func<Test<T>, T> CreateGetter<T>(PropertyInfo info)
{
    Type type = info.ReflectedType;

    PropertyInfo genericProperty = type.MakeGenericType(typeof(T)).GetProperty(info.Name);

    return (source) => (T)genericProperty.GetValue(source);
}
```

Otherwise i would suggest this:

```
public static Func<Test<T>, T> GetGenericPropertyDelegate<T>(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyInfo genericProperty = typeof(Test<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T)).GetProperty(propertyName);

    return (source) => (T)genericProperty.GetValue(source);
}
```

usage:

```
public void Test<T>(ITest<T> x)
{
    var getter = GetGenericPropertyDelegate<int>("Item");

    Assert(getter(x).Equals(x.Item));
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but this isn't what I'm trying to do. The question was "can the test be made to pass by implementing `CreateGetter `?", not "can the test be made to pass by changing the test?"

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the generic type first and then you can create the delegate from the `MethodInfo` in the usual way.

```
var target = typeof(ITest<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(int));
var prop = target.GetProperty("Item");
var dlg = prop.GetMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(target, prop.PropertyType));
```